# Оператор ?. выдаёт ошибку в TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Компилирую этот код:

```js
const obj = {};
console.log(obj?.fs);
```

TypeScript выдаёт ошибку: `index.ts:2:18 - error TS2339: Property 'fs' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Что посоветуете?

Comment: `const obj: { fs?: string } = {}` либо `const obj = {} as { fs: string }`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: пожалуйста.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо огромное человек `entithat` за ответ в комментариях
Это сработало:

```js
const obj: { fs?: string } = {}
```